# How to combine two dicts with different key, value pairs into a single dictionary and write the result into a txt file with header and their values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dicts as of below:

```
dict1 = {'name':'john', 'age':43}
dict2 = {'sex':'male', 'place':'southafrica'}
```

Note: `dict2`'s keys and values can change all the time

How do we combine two dicts like this:

```
res = {'name':'john', 'sex':'male', 'place':'southafrica'}
```

I want to write this into a txt file with delimiter '|' like below"

```
name|sex|place
john|male|southafrica
```

How can we achieve this with python?

Comment: What happen to 'age' 43 ?

Comment: Why isn't age printed? And possible duplicate of [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: Do you care if one of the original dictionaries gets modified? You can call `dict1.update(dict2)` to add dict2 to dict1.

Comment: we dont need dict1['age'] for this @wim

Comment: There are two separate questions here; please ask a single question per post. The second part is solved with [`csv.DictWriter(outputfile, delimiter='|')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter).

Comment: @WalterWhite: then make it explicit as to what is and what isn't needed. What are the rules of the combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building from Karl's comment:

```
dict1 = {'name':'john', 'age':43}
dict2 = {'sex':'male', 'place':'southafrica'}

# combine the dicts
dict1.update(dict2)

# Get the keys
keys = dict1.keys()

# Get the values corresponding to each key in proper order
values = [dict1[key] for key in keys]

# Write to a file
fout = open('fileout.txt','w')
print('|'.join(map(str, keys)), file=fout)
print('|'.join(map(str, values)), file=fout)
fout.close()
```

Comment: Thanks @killian95. Made changes according to the comments. Now it works.

Comment: Can you show how to write into a file with delimiter without just printing? @killian95

Comment: Sure, updating my answer now.

Comment: Its not writing into a file. The file is empty. It throws an error saying unsupported operand >> ? @kiilian95

Comment: Ah, you must be using python 3. My syntax was for python 2. Updating.